# Specializing a function for distinctly typed parameters

Tags: haskell, functional-dependencies

I'd like to write a function `bar :: Foo a -> Foo b -> Foo c`, such that if `a` and `b` is the same type, then `c` is of that type, otherwise it is `()`. I suspect that functional dependencies would help me, but I'm not sure how. I write

```
class Bar a b c | a b -> c where
  bar :: Foo a -> Foo b -> Foo c 

instance Bar x x x where
  bar (Foo a) (Foo b) = Foo a

instance Bar x y () where
  bar _ _ = Foo ()
```

but obviously, `bar (Foo 'a') (Foo 'b')` satisfies both instances. How would I declare an instance for two distinct types `x /= y` only?

Comment: This is intrinsically overlapping: what are you gonna do about the case `Foo () -> Foo () -> Foo ()`? Obviously, both your instances behave the same then anyway, but you can't expect GHC to be able to prove such stuff.

Comment: `() -> () -> ()` falls strictly into my first intended category. In the code I posted they do overlap - that's exactly my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. You can do this pretty easily with `OverlappingInstances` and `UndecidableInstances`. Since this is probably intended as a closed world sort of class, undecidable instances are probably no big deal for you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances
 , OverlappingInstances, TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances #-}

data Foo a = Foo a deriving Show

class Bar a b c | a b -> c where
  bar :: Foo a -> Foo b -> Foo c 

instance Bar x x x where
  bar (Foo a) (Foo b) = Foo a

instance (u ~ ())=> Bar x y u where
  bar _ _ = Foo ()
```

Notice the last instance: if we put `()` in the instance head it becomes *more specific* than the other instance and would get matched first, so we instead use the type equality assertion from `TypeFamilies` (`~`). I learned this [from Oleg](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/typeEQ.html#old-implementations).

Notice how this behaves:

```
*Main> bar (Foo 'a') (Foo 'b')
Foo 'a'
*Main> bar (Foo 'a') (Foo True)
Foo ()
*Main> bar (Foo 'a') (Foo 1)

<interactive>:16:1:
    Overlapping instances for Bar Char b0 c0
      arising from a use of `bar'
    Matching instances:
      instance [overlap ok] u ~ () => Bar x y u
        -- Defined at foo.hs:13:10
      instance [overlap ok] Bar x x x -- Defined at foo.hs:9:10
    (The choice depends on the instantiation of `b0, c0'
     To pick the first instance above, use -XIncoherentInstances
     when compiling the other instance declarations)
    In the expression: bar (Foo 'a') (Foo 1)
    In an equation for `it': it = bar (Foo 'a') (Foo 1)

<interactive>:16:20:
    No instance for (Num b0) arising from the literal `1'
    The type variable `b0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus three others
    In the first argument of `Foo', namely `1'
    In the second argument of `bar', namely `(Foo 1)'
    In the expression: bar (Foo 'a') (Foo 1)
```

Also in GHC 7.8 you'll have access to closed type families which I think (and hope, as it's relevant to my interests) will be able to handle this in a more palatable way, but the details get [a bit confusing](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families#Closed_family_simplification)

Comment: I'll take this answer as *"you can't and you shouldn't"* :).

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė well, this does what you were looking for, right (although you may not have anticipated how this would behave in the face of polymorphism)? If you want to do this *and* intend `Bar` to be a usual open class, then you're right.